# 'Themeing' my Slider in WP with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a pretty basic 'featured-list - image slider' implemented above my content in my custom Wordpress theme. I'm wondering how I could hardcode the PHP in between to connect my slider with my 'theme'. **I'm trying to '*theme*' the slider so that the content is pulled via 'Recent-Posts' or via a 'Category'. And how I could set the 'Featured Imgs' to display as the photo within the slider and to display in my alotted thumbnail sections in list area?**

Here's a screenshot of the jQuery I plugin I picked this up on;
[image]
  *(Their demo is broke, so.)*

**Below is the markup I have implemented.**

```
  <div id="featured" >  
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">  
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>David King – on his True Crime thriller</span></a></li>  
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="images/image2-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Tips from Steve Perry</span></a></li>  
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="images/image3-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Tips from Chuck Berry</span></a></li>  
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>SFIRS</span></a></li>  
     </ul>  




    <!-- First Content -->  
    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">  
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" />  
        <div class="info" >  
        <h2><a href="#" >David King – on his True Crime thriller</a></h2>  
        <p>David King is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum...<a href="#" >read more</a></p>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <!-- Second Content -->  
    <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" />  
        <div class="info" >  
        <h2><a href="#" >Tips from Steve Perry</a></h2>  
        <p>Steve Perry is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum...<a href="#" >read more</a></p>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <!-- Third Content -->  
    <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
        <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" />  
        <div class="info" >  
        <h2><a href="#" >Tips from Chuck Berry</a></h2>  
        <p>Chuck Berry is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum...<a href="#" >read more</a></p>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <!-- Fourth Content -->  
    <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />  
        <div class="info" >  
        <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>  
        <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

[**Updated Q here, with up to date attempt, still not solved**](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?840162-Help-with-Theming-my-jQuery-CSS-slider-in-WP-to-Dashboard!!&p=5084697#post5084697)

***LATEST UPDATE:*** Still trying to get images to pull in. I've tried Suni's suggestions but still can't get them to pull in within the slider (They end up populating outside of)

*Some I've tried below:*

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >'; the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); echo '</a>'; } ?>
?> 


<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');    
?> 


 <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); <a  href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >  
?> 

    <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >'; the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); echo '</a>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Although you think it's basic, there is more to it than you think.

Comment: A couple hours have proven that! But still, suggestions?

Comment: Try this to start. http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: You'd want a custom loop. http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: can you provide a demo link ? where you working on it? so that we could help you

Comment: Your essentially asking for someone to do the work for you, that's not help, http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hi, you can user `get_posts` to fetch posts.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Below is the code .. Not Tested ..

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme'

 */

//get_header(); ?>        
<div id="content"> 

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<!--Your slider code goes here-->

<?php 
$args = array(
              'numberposts'     => 5,
              'orderby'         => 'post_date',
              'order'           => 'DESC'
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
?>       

<div id="featured" >  
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">

<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?> 

<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo $i; ?>">
  <a href="#fragment-1"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/>
    <span>
      <?php the_title(); ?><br />
      <p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </span>
  </a>
</li> 
<?php $i++; 
endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>

<!-- First Content -->  
<div id="fragment-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
  <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>" alt="" />  
  <div class="info">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more</a></p>  
  </div>  
</div>  
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>


</div>  

<!--Your slider code goes here-->
<!-- End Featured Lists Image Slider -->        

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tested this solution out and it works me as far I can test it, ie, I can't test the javascript part. The only small error is that first list does not have a closing ul tag. I would edit it, but I don't have edit privileges yet.

Comment: Awesome Sunil - thanks! Any suggestions on getting the a 'featured_image' to populate slider?

Comment: hi Cam, you using the_post_thumbnail

$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');

<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

let me know if its clear ..

Comment: Thanks Sunil; so add this: <?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
   echo '</a>';
 }
 ?>

Comment: I've read it states to add within the loop / or should I add within slider?

Comment: hi cam add with in  foreach loop..

foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);

Comment: Thanks Sunny, I've made multiple attempts and they seem to pull the images OUTSIDE of the slider. I've updated question above with what I've tried -

Comment: This can be the end of this question. But now I've lost the JS functionality of the slider actually sliding or rotating. I've posted new discussion / Q - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890331/making-my-slider-rotate-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it.

You'll need essentially two loops over the posts you want to use - one to create the tabs, one to create the content. To avoid doing two DB queries, cache the posts from one query in an array and use a foreach loop over that array.

Use a custom query to get the post objects which you want to use in your slider: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

*Disclaimer: This will not work verbatim, but should give you the framework required*

```
<?php

$post_data = array();

// Use a custom query to get the posts you want for your slider
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $post_data[] = $post;

endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>

<div id="featured" >

    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">  

    <?php 
    foreach($post_data as $key => $post){

      // Out put the markup + data from the $post object that you need for your tabs

    } 
    ?>

    </ul>

    <?php 
    foreach($post_data as $key => $post){

      // Out put the markup + data from the $post object that you need for your slider fragments

    } 
    ?>

</div>
```